# Area of an ellipse inclined in xy plane

Tags: conic-sections, area

Find the area of figure enclosed by the curve $5x^2 + 6xy + 2y^2
 + 7x + 6y + 6 = 0$

My approach, the above is an equation of ellipse as $3^2-40\le 0$. The area of a std ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ is $\pi ab$. I need to transform the above equation so that major axis is either x-axis or y-axis. I am unable to do so

Comment: You have a rotated and translated ellipse. Take a look at the answers for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280937

Comment: actually, if you have ellipse without any linear terms, just some $a x^2 + bxy + c y^2 = d$   with $a,d, 4ac - b^2$ all positive, the area can be found by formula. That is, the translation is enough.

Comment: Try this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594693/how-to-put-2x2-4xy-6y2-6x-2y-6-in-canonical-form/594707#594707

Answer (score 1):

By letting $x=X+2$ and $y=Y-\frac{9}{2}$ the equation is reduced to
$$ 5X^2+6XY+2Y^2=(X,Y)\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 3 \\ 3 & 2\end{pmatrix}(X,Y)^T=\frac{1}{2} $$
where the involved (symmetric, positive definite) matrix has determinant $1$.
 It follows that the enclosed area equals the area enclosed by
$$ \tilde{X}^2+\tilde{Y}^2 = \frac{1}{2}, $$
i.e. $\large{\frac{\pi}{2}}$. This works since the area only depends on the product of the eigenvalues, which is the determinant.