# Minkowski's convex body theorem and binary quadratic forms

Tags: quadratic-forms, geometry-of-numbers

Saw this question in NZM and have a lot of difficulties trying to start.

Consider the binary quadratic form $f(x,y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ with $a > 0$ and $d = b^2 − 4ac < 0$. Show that there exist integers $x$ and $y$, not both zero, such that $\lvert ax^2 + bxy + cy^2\rvert \leq \frac{2}{\pi{}}\sqrt{−d}$.

I tried to use Minkowski's convex body theorem, but to no avail. What could be the possible convex symmetric subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to choose in this case such that the volume is greater than 4?

Answer (score 1):

This is Problem 12 in Section 6.4, "The Geometry of Numbers," in I. Niven, H. S. Zuckerman, H. L. Montgomery, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers,* 5th ed., Wiley (New York), 1991.

First note that the absolute value signs are superfluous because the assumptions that $d < 0$ and $a > 0$ imply that $f(x, y) \ge 0$.  (See Definition 3.5 and Theorem 3.11. Those without the book can refer to the [Wikipedia article on binary quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form).)

The assumption [$d < 0$ also implies that
$$ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 \leq \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{−d}$$
represents an ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant) and its interior.  That answers your question except for the following subtlety:

The [area of our ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/247392/389981) is equal to 4, not greater than 4 as you asked for in order to use [Minkowski's convex body theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_theorem) to complete the problem.  Instead, use a [modified version of the theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90158/minkowskis-theorem-in-lang-algebraic-number-theory), also given in Corollary 6.22 and Problem 9, to complete the problem.  The modification allows the area to be greater than *or equal to* 4 if the set of points is closed, which is true for an ellipse and its interior.