# Quadratic forms: Existence of $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ such that $P(x,y) < 2\sqrt{\lvert \det(P) \rvert}$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, geometry-of-numbers

I am stuck on the following exercise:

> Show that for any non-degenerate quadratic form $P$ over $\mathbb{R}$, that is either indefinite or positive definite, exists an integer point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ such that
>
> $$0 < P(x,y) < 2\sqrt{\lvert \det(P) \rvert}.$$

From the lecture I know about Minkowski's Theorem, but I do not see how to use this here. Could you please help me?

EDIT: The part with positive definite forms was already solved here:

[Minkowski's convex body theorem and binary quadratic forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027014/minkowskis-convex-body-theorem-and-binary-quadratic-forms?noredirect=1&lq=1)

So we are only left with the case of indefinite forms.